# Aligning content within columns based on column position

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm creating a grid which has three columns. The grid boxes each have a div inside which has a maximum width of `280px`, and sometimes the grid columns are wider than this. I want to align the content in the grid boxes so that the left column are aligned to the left, the central column is aligned to the center, and the right column is aligned to the right. See the image below for my desired result:

[image]

Currently I'm using the CSS `justify-items: justify` rule on the grid container element. My **current result** is below:

[image]

What can I do with CSS to produce the layout in my desired layout diagram?

Comment: are you allowed to use flex..?

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt Yeah, why I don't see why not

Comment: "Currently I'm using the CSS justify-items: justify" Where? You have not included your code. Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS Grid for this, but (as far as I know) you will have to target items on specific `grid-columns` and align them as you need using the `justify-self` property.

The special case is a row with only one item.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsjwx0kb/2/)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background: pink;
}

.item:nth-of-type(3n) {
  justify-self: end;
}

.item:nth-of-type(3n + 2) {
  justify-self: center;
}

.item:nth-of-type(3n + 1):last-of-type {
  grid-column: 2;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to make your `item` 33% wide, and then left, center and right align each *column's* content using the `nth-child` selector.

For this you can use `inline-block` or `flex` etc., and in this first sample I used Flexbox.

Stack snippet

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex .item {
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 10px);
  border: 1px dotted black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
}

.flex .item:nth-child(3n+2) div {
  margin: 0 auto;                  /* center align every 3rd, start from item 2  */
}

.flex .item:nth-child(3n+3) div {
  margin-left: auto;               /* right align every 3rd, start from item 3  */
}

.flex .item div {
  max-width: 280px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">
    <div>Some content that can be max 280px wide</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Some content that can be max 280px wide</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Some content that can be max 280px wide</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Some content that can be max 280px wide</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Some content that can be max 280px wide</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

For those who need to support browsers that doesn't support Flexbox (or has buggy behavior), this one use `inline-block` and `float`

```css
.parent::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.parent .item {
  float: left;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 10px);
  border: 1px dotted black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
}

.parent .item:nth-child(3n+2) {
  text-align: center;              /*  center align every 3rd, start from item 2  */
}

.parent .item:nth-child(3n+3) {
  text-align: right;               /*  right align every 3rd, start from item 3  */
}

.parent .item div {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 280px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: lightgray;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">
    <div>Some content that can be max 280px wide</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Some content that can be max 280px wide</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Some content that can be max 280px wide</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Some content that can be max 280px wide</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Some content that can be max 280px wide</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Flexbox**. Flexbox makes it very easy to implement these kind of layouts.

You have to use `justify-content:space-between`.

**[Fiddle Link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/bhuwanb9/0t185wza/1/)**

Comment: Hi, I've spotted an issue with this! If I have less items than the number of rows, the contents glue themselves to each side, leaving a huge gap between the items. See the image for more: https://i.imgur.com/FLWOeLk.png

Comment: _**less items than the number of rows**_....? don't understand...could you share a fiddle link...?

Comment: Please see the imgur link. You can see the 3rd row's middle column is empty because there aren't enough items in the row to fill up the entire space.